Ошибка при установке библиотек для Rubu on Rails
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Ruby\chat_app> bundle add devise turbo-rails
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Ruby\chat_app> rails generate devise:install
C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53:in `exec': No such file or directory - "C:/Program Files/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53:in `block in exec_app'
        from C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `loop'
        from C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `exec_app'
        from C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Program Files/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Program Files/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ivash/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.3/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby32-x64/bin/rails:32:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby32-x64/bin/rails:32:in `<main>'

Операционная система Windows 11
